# Heap Buffer Overflow when converting UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> to String

Tags: ios, swift, overflow, heap-memory

I'm getting an error from Address Sanitizer when doing the following:

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: 4, alignment: 1)
pointer.storeBytes(of: 77, as: UInt8.self)
pointer.advanced(by: 1).storeBytes(of: 105, as: UInt8.self)
(pointer+2).storeBytes(of: 107, as: UInt8.self)
(pointer+3).storeBytes(of: 101, as: UInt8.self)

let typedPointer = pointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 4)


let readableData = String(cString: typedPointer)
```

I get Heap buffer overflow, but I'm not understanding why. In my actual code I have a much more complex pointer, but even in this simple example I consistently hit the issue. I'm thinking it has something to do with String(cString: typedPointer), but I'm not seeing how I could have allocated the wrong memory size that would cause any of the heap headers or data to be stomped.

***UPDATE - See Answer below***

Looks like I need a null terminator as the last byte in the pointer or the String will not know where the pointer ends.

Answer (score 1):

Other options...

You can create `Data` from your `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`:

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: 4, alignment: 1)
pointer.storeBytes(of: 77, as: UInt8.self)
pointer.advanced(by: 1).storeBytes(of: 105, as: UInt8.self)
(pointer+2).storeBytes(of: 107, as: UInt8.self)
(pointer+3).storeBytes(of: 101, as: UInt8.self)

let data = Data(bytes: pointer, count: 4)
let readableData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Or else, `String.init(bytes:encoding:)` is another initializer which does not claim null-terminated sequence:

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: 4, alignment: 1)
pointer.storeBytes(of: 77, as: UInt8.self)
pointer.advanced(by: 1).storeBytes(of: 105, as: UInt8.self)
(pointer+2).storeBytes(of: 107, as: UInt8.self)
(pointer+3).storeBytes(of: 101, as: UInt8.self)

let urbp = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: 4)
let readableData = String(bytes: urbp, encoding: .utf8)
```

Please try.

Comment: Both these work, but do rely on it being in .utf8 format, which fits most needs. Great answer! + 1

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

According to the documentation of `String(cString: fooParam)`

> - Parameter cString: A pointer to a null-terminated UTF-8 code sequence.

If the data you are sending in is not null-terminated, this initializer will not know where the pointer data ends and will have "unexpected behavior" sometimes failing, sometimes succeeding.

The solution is, if the data that you're trying to pass in is not null-terminated, to add in the null-terminator.

For example:

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: 5, alignment: 1)
pointer.storeBytes(of: 77, as: UInt8.self)
pointer.advanced(by: 1).storeBytes(of: 105, as: UInt8.self)
(pointer+2).storeBytes(of: 107, as: UInt8.self)
(pointer+3).storeBytes(of: 101, as: UInt8.self)
(pointer+4).storeBytes(of: 0, as: UInt8.self)

let typedPointer = pointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 5)


let readableData = String(cString: typedPointer)
```

In the case of what I was actually doing, I didn't have a raw reference, but a typed one. The same thing was achieved by doing

```
somePointer.advanced(by: 4).pointee = 0
```